# Create table on SQL server with SparkR

Tags: sql, r, apache-spark, databricks, sparkr

From R notebook on Databricks I would like to create a table on SQL server. I am able to read SQL tables with the following:

```
library('magrittr')
library('SparkR')
    conn =  "jdbc:sqlserver://someconnection.windows.net:1433;database=some_db;user=user_name;password=user_password"
      
    data = SparkR::read.jdbc(conn, "(select top 100 * from TableA) as result") %>% SparkR::collect()
```

However, if I try something like this:

```
data = SparkR::read.jdbc(conn, "(CREATE TABLE TableA (PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255))) as result")
```

It does not work, it returns

```
Error : Error in jdbc : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: create table has no result set, that you can pass to

Comment: I meant it does not create a table, I do not care about result set.

Comment: you as a as result, that is invalid, so remove it

Comment: @nbk I tried and still did not work.

Comment: Please add also the new. Command that you tried, you probably forgot to remove the parenthesis